# Cannot insert radio button data into mariadb (mysql)

Tags: php, html, mariadb

I have tried many different solutions to no avail you will see the attempts.
The columns in question are tinyint 1 pass and 0 fail. From poweradapter down. The textarea goes into the database just fine. I've tried enumerating the boolean and print_r($_POST and now im just lost.

*Also put through mysqli_real_escape

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $tester = $_POST['tester'];
    $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
    $poweradapter = $_POST['poweradapter'];

$query  = "INSERT INTO tested (tester, manufacturer, model, serial, poweradapter)
VALUES ('$tester','$manufacturer','$model','$serial','$poweradapter');";

<div class="fb-radio-group form-group field-poweradapter"><label for="poweradapter" class="fb-radio-group-label">Power Adapter<span class="fb-required">*</span><span class="tooltip-element" tooltip="Plug into Laptop - Charges the Battery">?</span></label>
    <div class="radio-group"><div class="radio"><label for="poweradapter-0"><input name="poweradapter" id="poweradapter-0" required="required" aria-required="true" value="1" type="radio">Pass</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label for="poweradapter-1"><input name="poweradapter" id="poweradapter-1" required="required" aria-required="true" value="0" type="radio">Fail</label></div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: print_r(@_POST) should be  print_r($_POST);  Mind the dollar sign instead of the @ symbol.

Comment: Ohh yeah it was a $ my brain is just fried.. all it does it print to screen. Doesn't go into table. All debug options are enabled and doesn't kick anything back as the syntax is correct. Apparently I'm forgetting something.

Answer (score 0):

Unless MariaDB works quite a bit differently than regular MySQL, it looks to me like you are only storing a MySQL statement in a variable without actually executing it.

You may want to do something like:

```
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO tested (tester, manufacturer, model, serial, poweradapter)
VALUES ('$tester','$manufacturer','$model','$serial','$poweradapter')";
```

With $db containing your database connection.

Comment: I'm executing it with mysqli_query($link,$query);.   Sorry new at stack overflow for help.. but thank you. The text area does get put in when I comment out the radio button variable

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose I'll just rewrite the form as the issue isn't the radio button entirely rather when I mix one of the textareas with it. Thank you all